# How can I change the color of the scrollbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-theme

The current problem is that our theme is inheriting from Theme.AppCompat, which appears to have a white scrollbar, and that is not visible on the white background.
I know that I can use

```
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroll_thumb</item>
```

And create a shape for the custom Scrollbar. But I only want to change it to a darker color. When I use a simple colored rectangle shape, it has a different width than the normal scrollbar.

Is this possible?

Comment: use android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"  into xml layout rather than in theme style.xml

Comment: thanks, but I want to change the theme, because it is used at many places and I do not want to edit all the layout files.

Comment: @bjornson Scrollbar thumb color is set to the `colorAccent` attribute in your app theme.  did you set it?

Comment: @Karan Mer, thanks for the info, colorAccent requires Api Level 21, but I need to support all the way back to level 15, any ideas how to set it for the old versions?

Comment: I will be offline for the afternoon, so I won't be able to reply for the next few hours.

Comment: you just need to use it as `android:colorAccent` for the older versions

Comment: thanks again Karan, but android:colorAccent still needs level 21, do you also know what will change besides the scrollbar, when this value is changed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ok, it is possible to use a color for the scrollbarThumbVertical item value, but this will change the width, so I set the size to 4dp, which

seems to be the same as in the other views with the native scrollbars

```
    <item name="android:scrollbarSize">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@color/scrollbar_thumb</item>
```

I don't like having to set the size, but I don't see any other way that would be cleaner.

Comment: Bjorn, where did you actually include those 2 lines?

Comment: Ok, I just found out. They should be inside the AppTheme style: `<style name="AppTheme"....>HERE</style>`

Comment: Good to hear you found it, i wasn't online, sorry.