# Android: change color of spinner's popup scrollbar

Tags: android, scrollbar, spinner, android-spinner, android-scrollbar

How can I change the color of the spinner's popup scrollbar?

For some reason the color of the scrollbar is currently white on a white background, it is not visible.

Comment: You mean the background color of the pop up?

Comment: I mean the color of the scrollbar of the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution for changing the scrollbar color globally:

[How can I change the color of the scrollbar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454126/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-scrollbar-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
add android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/yourdawable //in your spinner
```

yourdrawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient android:startColor="your color" android:endColor="your color"
        android:angle="45"/>

    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of spinner to change the spinner color.

Make a style in style.xml like below:

```
<style name="App_SpinnerStyle" >
        <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

then in xml of spinner :

```
android:popupTheme="@style/App_SpinnerStyle"
```

Tried and tested!!

Comment: In my case it work with android:theme="@style/App_SpinnerStyle".