# Android How to change scrollbar color in Spinner

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-spinner, android-scrollbar

How can I change the default color of scrollbar present in the spinner? 
is it possible to do it on an app level?

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/location"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/input_borde"/>
```

Comment: Could you check this answer [Android: change color of spinner's popup scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163122/android-change-color-of-spinners-popup-scrollbar)

Comment: It's not working on spinner . Those are working on scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/youdrawable`

**For example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient android:startColor="#66C0C0C0" android:endColor="#66C0C0C0"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

Spinners in Android doesn't have a Scrollbar, the scrollbar exists within the listView maintained inside the Spinner, and has no public access.

There's a run-time way to override it in the link below

**Resource:** [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014485/cant-make-spinners-scrollbar-always-visible-android/12644532#12644532)

**Custom spinner:** [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812302/spinners-scrollbar-style/19820350#19820350)